# When to use the prepositions 'in' and 'inside'

Tags: word-choice

Could you please tell me which one of the following sentences is correct? I'm interested in understanding when it's best to use either 'in' or 'inside'.

> The cinema is very cold.
>   In the cinema is very cold.
>   Inside the cinema, it's very cold.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners and thanks for your question. I want you to be aware of why I edited it. The system flagged your question for review because it was so short. I think it's a good question and I also think you will get better answers if you write it in a more inviting way. I've given my suggestion. You can reject my edits and rewrite it in any way you choose, or keep it. Generally, the more detail you can give about why you're asking the question and what you've already understood about it the better answer and the more votes you'll get for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is fine.
The second sentence is not a complete sentence because it is missing a subject.
As for the last one, I think you should go with `It's very cold inside the cinema.`. As for the meaning, it is more specific but overall mean the same as the first sentence.