# what is the difference between 'in and inside'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

The prepositions *in* and *inside* confuse me in these sentences:

1. She is **in** my room.
2. She is **inside** my room.
3. It is cold **in** my room.
4. It is cold **inside** my room.

Which one is better? And what is the difference between *in* and *inside* in those sentences?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of into vs in vs inside](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18366/usage-of-into-vs-in-vs-inside). Also [When to use the prepositions 'in' and 'inside'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/210801/when-to-use-the-prepositions-in-and-inside) and [Should I use "inside the drawer" or "in the drawer" when I am talking about a small object?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/305230/should-i-use-inside-the-drawer-or-in-the-drawer-when-i-am-talking-about-a-sm), among others.